# Grep Command In Java To Print 5 Lines Before And After Keyword

Tags: java, unix, grep

I'm trying to write code that will print the 5 lines before the keyword and the 5 lines after the word. I understand that grep has a command that allows you to do this, but I'm not seeing it as an option as part of the Unix4J library.

For example, I'm trying to run this command on each file that I iterate through in the code "grep -C 5 Stack trace:".

In addition to running this command I'm also trying to capture the output of this command. I've been researching for examples online on how to do this using grep, but I haven't found any examples that are relative to my context. Below is the code I have been able to write up to now. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import org.unix4j.Unix4j;
import org.unix4j.builder.Unix4jCommandBuilder;
import org.unix4j.line.Line;
import org.unix4j.unix.Grep;
import org.unix4j.unix.grep.GrepOptions;

public class Logs {

    public String GetLogs() {


        File dir = new File("C:\\alerts\\logs");
        File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();

        List<Line> lines = null;
        if(directoryListing != null) {
            for (File child: directoryListing) {
                //Write code 
            }
        }



        return null;
    }
```

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: _Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._

Comment: The Unix Way is to use `find`, pipe the output into `grep` and then do whatever processing is necessary in another pipeline step written in whatever programming language you prefer.

Comment: Hi @KarolDowbecki, this is not homework. This is work related. I'm trying to find out if there is a way to use the Unix4j library to grep on a file and print the 5 lines before the keyword and the 5 lines after the keyword.